# Method arguments reference or not

Tags: c#

Could someone explaine please i thought it get just passed by ref when i explicite do it with `ref`?

```
var user = new User { Name = "MyName" };
ChangeNameToOtherName(user);      // After method call user.name is "OtherName" < confusing
ChangeNameToOtherName(ref user);  // After method call user.name is "OtherName"

var name = "MyName";
ChangeNameToOtherName(name);      // After method call name is "MyName"
ChangeNameToOtherName(ref name);  // After method call name is "OtherName"
```

Comment: You are passing string in parameter. In c# string is more like value type. That is why in first method call of second case the name is not changed.

Comment: public sealed class String : IComparable, ICloneable, IConvertible, IComparable<string>, IEnumerable<char>, IEnumerable, IEquatable<string>, what i ve learned is class = reference type or not?

Comment: A string is a [*reference*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61(v=vs.90).aspx) type.

Comment: In c#, after each string operation a new string is created and the result is stored in the new reference. So, the values in old reference is not changed. This makes the string sort of immutable. That is why I said "more like value type."

Comment: Try to use something like `user = new User { Name = "OtherName" };` in your `ChangeNameToOtherName()` and you'll see the difference.

Comment: @AviralSingh As you see from the code in the question, that's not true at all.

Comment: @svick yeah that what i was missing thanks

Comment: `ref` parameters have nothing to do with reference types. Both value and reference types can be passed either by value or by reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ref` keyword allows you to change the reference of the passed parameter, i.e. change the parameter itself directly.

I assume your method body looks something like this:

```
void ChangeNameToOtherName(User user) {
  user.Name = "Other name";
}
```

Here, you are passing a reference to an instance of type user. Changing a property on this instance will modify the original instance. If you assign a new object, the change will not be visible outside the method: `user = new User { Name = "Name" };`

Strings are immutable in .NET, and you cannot modify an existing instance. You can only assign a new instance to a variable. But changing the instance a variable references is not visible outside of a function (unless, passed by `ref` of course).

Passing class instances to a function will call the function with a reference to that instance. You can change the instance, but you cannot change the reference to that instance.

Comment: There's a great article that explains this... http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html